# C program won't get access to textile

Tags: c, fopen, exc-bad-access, scanf

Just to make it clear - I'm a beginner in C.

When my program is running (using Xcode), no values correspond to the values in "resultfortran.txt". Instead, they become very small, very large or zero (looks random). For example, the variable n becomes 0, even though the first line in "resultfortran.txt" is 10. The variables min and max also becomes very small (and don't get the values at line 2 and 3).

I have searched the web all day, and asked my fellow students. If it is of interest, I got the error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" on the line where the file is opened, but that error has (some how?) disappeared. And yes, "resultfortran.txt2 is in the same folder as main.m.

The start of the program is shown below:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


static void draw( void )
{
int n,i,j;
float step,min,max,x,y,scaled;
float matrix[1000][1000];

FILE *fp; //reads input file
fp=fopen("resultfortran.txt", "r");
fscanf(fp,"%d",&n); //Gives n the value of the first line.
step=(1.0/n); //Defines step size
fscanf(fp,"%f",&min); //Gives min the value of the second line.
fscanf(fp,"%f",&max); //Gives max the value of the third line.

for (i=0;i<n+1;i=i+1)
{

    for (j=0;j<n+1;j=j+1)
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%f",&matrix[i][j]);
    }
}
... not finished here ...
```

The first lines of the file "resultfortran.txt" (which is a output from a fortran script) is shown below:

```
10
0.00000000
0.500000000
0.0000000000
0.0025000002
0.0100000007
0.0225000009
0.0400000028
0.0625000000
0.0900000036
0.1224999949
0.1600000113
0.2024999857
0.2500000000
0.0025000002
0.0050000008
0.0125000002
```

Comment: You can start by checking the return value of `fopen()`.

Comment: `float matrix[1000][1000];` probably, Large to ensure the stack. change to `static float matrix[1000][1000];` or ensure by `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're "a beginner in C", I want to first welcome you to what is a very rigorous but rewarding language. Though, to be fair, I wouldn't consider someone who is writing operating system code to be a "*beginner"* in C.

I'll gladly assist you and update this answer as we proceed. My first suggestion is as follows:

The first thing you *always* should do when doing file operations (like opening one) is to check the results of the execution! For example, if you read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) on `fopen()`, you'll see that `fopen()` will

> return a FILE pointer. Otherwise, NULL is returned and errno is set to
>   indicate the error.

So, use something similar to the code below to make sure that your file is opening as expected:

```
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("fopen did not work! Check errno %d\n", errno);
}
else {
    printf("fopen workd!\n");
}
```

*I will update this answer once you get back to me on the results of implementing the code above.*

Comment: Even more helpful than printing the value of `errno` is to use `perror` or `strerror` to get a human-readable message..

Comment: The code you suggested returns "fopen worked", so that doesn't seem to be the problem. The variables n, min and max still has the values 0 (or very small numbers) after fscanf.

Comment: I found out now. The problem was that the file wasn't located where i had dragged it. So by inserting the full path, the file was read properly. Thanks for taking time to help me. @8protons

Comment: @mathia No problem. I am curious about the fact that, "The code you suggested returns "fopen worked"" yet "the problem was that the file wasn't located where i had dragged it." I'd suspect that an incorrect file path would have returned an errno.